# Angular 2 Usage of Http Observable and Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http, angular2-pipe

I have a service that call a REST endpoint:

```
import { Task } from './task';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
    constructor(private http: Http){
    }
    getTasks() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/tasks').map(res => res.json()).map(rest => rest._embedded.tasks);
    }
}
```

The endpoint returns a result like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "tasks": [
      {
        "title": "zxc",
        "description": "zxc",
        "status": "New",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/1"
          },
          "task": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "asd",
        "description": "qweqwe",
        "status": "New",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/2"
          },
          "task": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/tasks"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

I use the service in this component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomp',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  tasks: Array<Task>;

  constructor(private taskService:TaskService) {
    taskService.getTasks()
    .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks, 
                err => console.error(err), 
                () => console.log('done'));
  }
}
```

And the template looks like this;

```
<task-details *ngFor="let task of tasks" [task]="task"></task-details>
```

This works as expected, but when I try to use a pipe in the template:

```
<task-details *ngFor="let task of tasks | WithStatus: TaskStatus.New" [task]="task"></task-details>
```

I got the error "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".

Here is the pipe implementation:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status';

@Pipe({ name: 'WithStatus', pure: true })
export class TaskStatusFilter implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
        console.log(value);// value is undefined
        return value.filter(item => item.status == args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `WithStatus: TaskStatus.New` what is TaskStatus.New? you don't have such thing anywhere....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On initial change detection cycle when ajax haven't been completed that time it tries to evaluate `bindings` and pass `tasks` value as in `undefined` to `WithStatus` pipe and it throws an error. For such case you have to handle it inside a Pipe only.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'WithStatus', pure: true })
export class TaskStatusFilter implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
        console.log(value);// value is undefined
        return (value || []).filter(item => item.status == args[0]);
    }
}
```

---

The other way would be you should inject `task-details` DOM inside DOM tree until ajax gets succeeded using `*ngIf` structural directive.

```
<template [ng-if]="tasks">
  <task-details 
    *ngFor="let task of tasks | WithStatus: TaskStatus.New" 
    [task]="task">
  </task-details>
</template>
```

Instead of `<template>` you can also use `<ng-container>` which allows to use the same syntax as inline *ngIf:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tasks">
  <task-details 
    *ngFor="let task of tasks | WithStatus: TaskStatus.New" 
    [task]="task">
  </task-details>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @yurzui sir, I didn't know about `ng-container`, I don't find any resource mentioning the same, could you provide a reference please, Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good documentation about `ng-container`. The best reference is this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/core/test/linker/ng_container_integration_spec.ts

Comment: @yurzui cool, once again I appreciate your help, you work at Angular 2 team?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***ngIf="task"**. It will not initialize your pipe until data arrives.

```
<div *ngIf="tasks" >
<task-details *ngFor="let task of tasks | WithStatus: TaskStatus.New" 
              [task]="task"></task-details>
</div>
```